# Doctrine2 should automatically merge associated entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building an order process, in which an `Order` object is built through many steps. After each step I put the partly finished `Order` object into the `session`, and in the final step I save it into the database.

During the steps I load other, (already existing) associated objects into my `Order` object(eg. `DiscountCoupon`). The problem is that when I save my `Order` to the `session` and then load it in the next step, all associated entities will be detached. So when I want to save it to the database, the `EntityManager` throws an exception, which asks for setting a `cascade=persist` on the relationship.

Of course, I dont need to persist those objects(they are already in the database). The obvious solution could be to change those associated objects to merged ones(using `EntityManager#merge` method), however, I have a rather complicated object structure with multiple levels of embedded entities, so doing the above process would be rather inconvinient.

Cannot Doctrine automatically do this task for me? So instead of 'complaining' about my detached entities, it could automatically merge them.

Comment: I don't know Doctrine, but: I'd probably not store objects in the session anyway, in case Doctrine objects need Resource items that cannot be correctly serialised. I'd store the primary keys of these object(s) in the session, so when they are retrieved, you can just do a select - and presumably in Doctrine you can request associated rows to be loaded with it automatically.

Comment: Well, that could be a solution but it would break the OO design(which I would really hate). This way I can use the same entity objects which I later save into the DB. These objects only store data, and other entity objects and all those can be serialized. Most of the objects are not in the DB(they are built right during the process) during the order process. The only problem is that items from the database get detached once saved into and loaded from the session.

Comment: I'd wager the detaching effect is due to the session limitation I mentioned. I'm sure there would be another object-based way to do this - just with the proviso that you have to recreate the objects involved in every page view.

Comment: The detaching effect is caused by the fact that references of the used entities have to be stored in the `EntityManager` and if I access an entity without using the `EntityManager` (eg. from the session), the `EntityManager` wont find the reference to it. When I use the merge command, it records the reference, sets the state of the entity to managed, and from that point on it works. I just do not know why it cannot be automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you'd be creating some serious magic if you tried to make it entirely automatic.

Your best bet is probably to implement a function with a signature like: mergeOrderEntities($Order, $EntityManager) which knows how to talk the Order structure and invoke EntityManager::merge() on all detached associated entities.

As to why doctrine doesn't do this automatically, I'm not sure.  I suspect there are use cases where auto-merging of entities could be dangerous, or at least undesirable.

Comment: The automation could be an option. The cascade attribute has a `merge` option.
`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DiscountCoupon", mappedBy="order", cascade={"merge"})`

But it does not help. What does it do actually? The documentation says nothing about it.
What I thought of is to create a function which recursively traverses an object and merges all the detached entites it finds. I just do not want to reinvent the wheel, so I'm asking first.

Comment: I feel you.  It might be worth asking about on the mailing list.

Comment: I asked it, and was suggested storing the form data in the session, so I build the Order object from the form data on every page load.